# .htaccess shorten middle part of url, keep string after last slash

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a mod_rewrite rule to do the following:

Request URL:

```
https://dev.website.com/user/name
```

to work as

```
https://dev.website.com/foo/bar/user/name
```

This is my current .htaccess mod_rewrite, but it's not working. 
Regex tools are matching the string, but apache isn't.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*\/user\/(.+)*$ ./foo/bar/user/$1
```

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^.*/(user/[^/]*)/?$ /foo/bar/$1 [L]`

Comment: RTFM. In `.htaccess`, the string you are matching against is everything after the trailing slash of the directory you're in. If that's the web root, `RewriteRule`s only see `user/name`.

Answer (score 0):

[revo's answer in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50484806//50498139#comment87982697_50484806) worked.

```
RewriteRule ^.*/(user/[^/]*)/?$ /foo/bar/$1 [L]
```